# what does this git code that I use for merging my branch with master branch actually do?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I'm new to get and understand most of how I'm using it, but when I want to merge to master and add my changes back I don't get what's going on.

This is my flow:

First I do my edits and commit them to my-branch. Then I do

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout my-branch
git merge master
```

so I think that in the first line

```
git checkout master
```

I'm switching to the master branch. I'm not entirely sure what that means. But I think that it means that if I commit something at that point it would change master directly. I do know that my files stay in the same shape and maintain all of my edits.

Then, I have no idea about the second line

```
git pull origin master
```

In the third line

```
git checkout my-branch
```

I'm switching back to my-branch (again, not entirely sure of the implications).

Then, finally, I merge the two.

```
git merge master
```

I have no idea where the unmerged files are, but when I initiate a pull request on the git website I do see the nice diff.

I'm also a bit confused as to why what I'm initiating on the website is a "pull request" because it seems more like a commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master
```

This switches to the `master` branch. Changes that are *committed* in `my-branch`, but not in `master` are removed, and changes that are committed in `master` but not in `my-branch` are applied to the repository. Yes, if you started changing and committing files now, you would be altering `master`.

Note that changes that you've made while in `my-branch` but **have not yet committed** will stick around. This can cause a conflict if commits in the branch you're switching to make changes to the same places. If there is a conflict, git won't let you switch branches until you either commit those changes, or `stash` them.

```
git pull origin master
```

This does two things:

1. It `fetch`es changes from `origin`, i.e. it downloads them into a local branch set up to track the remote branch. This local remote-tracking branch isn't something you would normally interact with, it's handled automatically by git. In fact, it won't even be shown with `git branch --list`.
2. It `merge`s those changes into `master`. Sometimes, you may have to perform manual merging if git cannot figure out how to do so safely by itself.

Note that this doesn't initiate a "pull request". It's called `pull` because it's pulling the remote changes into the local repository. A pull request is simply asking someone else to pull from you.

```
git checkout my-branch
```

This is the same as the previous checkout, just in the opposite direction.

```
git merge master
```

This merges all the changes that `master` has, but `my-branch` does not, into `my-branch`. Thus, `my-branch` has everything `master` has, but `master` **does not** have any new changes from `my-branch`.

Comment: what does this mean? "Changes that are in my-branch, but not in master are removed, and changes that are in master but not in my-branch are applied to the repository." I can still see the changes that I made in my-branch in the file in the folder. Or am I confused?

Comment: @PaulBailey Were those changes actually committed?

Comment: @PaulBailey I added a bit near the top about that. Uncommitted changes will stick around when switching branches, but may prevent you from switching branches if they conflict.

Comment: @PaulBailey Oh, wait, you said they *were* committed. Hmm... that is strange. Will have to look into that more later. It might be worth adding a minimal example of that behavior to your question.

Comment: Looked back at it and you are correct. Sorry, I was confused.